# Не срабатывает required = false?

Tags: java, spring-boot, аннотации

Есть запрос PostNewProfile:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/profile/my", consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
 public ResponseEntity<?> postNewProfile(
   @RequestParam(value = "photo", required = false) MultipartFile photo,
   @RequestParam(value = "email", required = false) String email,
   @RequestParam(value = "password", required = false) String password,
   @RequestParam(value = "removePhoto", required = false) Integer removePhoto,
   @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name
  ) {
try {
   ResultResponseWithErrors response = userService.postNewProfile(photo, name,
       email, password, removePhoto);
   return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
 }
```

}

Так вот, если параметр photo не задан, то запрос не срабатывает, хотя required = false проставлен, т. е. этот параметр не должен быть обязательным, подскажите пожалуйста, что не так в коде. Когда же photo передается - запрос срабатывает нормально

Comment: Удалите каталог `build` в проекте и запуститесь еще раз.

Comment: нет такого, запустил maven clean и запустил, все равно

Comment: Что означает `запрос не срабатывает`? Какой http status он возвращает в этом случае? Метод контроллера вызывается? Уточнения вносите кнопкой "править".

Comment: {"timestamp":"2020-09-17T18:28:19.270+0000","status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","message":"Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported","path":"/api/profile/my"}

Comment: добавил content-type application/json, все равно не работает

Comment: у тебя случайно нет ещё других `POST` мэпингов на `/profile/my`?

Comment: Зачем посылать json на сервер если он не поддерживается? Надо привести примеры, какое значение имеет photo, перед отправкой.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему просто - декомпозиция, сделал два метода для запроса - один с multipartfile photo, а другой для json, в consumes четко прописал какой content-type в каждом методе работает норм. Всем спасибо за участие